# how to reference to data from listviews on different tabpages?

Tags: vb.net, listview, tabcontrol

i have several tabpages in one tabcontrol, each contains nothing but a listview. I need to get the data/items from the listview in the selected tab. My problem is, I can't refer to the listview. I tried

`exportpath = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls(0).`

but at this point, the IDE doesn't know that there's a listview, so I can't choose the

```
.items(i).tostring
```

The variables to create the tabpage and the listviews are already overwritten at this moment. Do you think I should choose another way to create the tabs and the listview (maybe create a list(of listviews) to remember the stuff), or is there a way close to my example try?

Best regards, Jan

Comment: `Controls(0)` is going to refer to the first control in the ZOrder which is a bad way to refer to a specific control.  It wounds like these are dynamically created? Either way, why not save the name of the control and use that eg `...Controls("NameOfTheLV")` you'll have to cast the result to `ListView` since you'll get it back as `Control`

Comment: Yes, I know it might be a problem with controls(0), but since there is only one control in the tab I guess it's not beautyful but OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dim lst as listview = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls(0)
dim exportpath as string = lst.items(i).tostring
```

? Would that work.
edit: assuming the listview is the only control you have there.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't load the control based off index in the collection.

I'm assuming since you are trying to access these dynamically you are also creating them dynamically?

Add a tag that can be referenced on the control or use the same naming convention. listview for the name ie MainListView# where # is just incremented or just assign all the tags on the listview to something consistent.

Then use helper function to loop through the controls collection for that tab and find the actual control.

Then loop through the collection of controls and find the one you want to target.

```
    Dim lstView As ListView = ControlNameStartsWith(TabControl1.SelectedTab, "MainListView")

    lstView.Items.Add("test")
```

**FUNCTIONS:**

```
Function ControlByTag(ByRef parent As Control, ByVal tag As String)

    For Each Cntl As Control In parent.Controls
            If Cntl.Tag.ToString.ToLower = tag.ToLower Then
                Return Cntl
                Exit For
            End If
    Next

    Return Nothing

End Function

Function ControlNameStartsWith(ByRef parent As Control, ByVal likePhrase As String)

    For Each Cntl As Control In parent.Controls

        If Cntl.Name.ToLower.StartsWith(likePhrase.ToLower) Then
            Return Cntl
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

    Return Nothing

End Function

Function ControlByName(ByRef parent As Control, ByVal name As String)

    For Each Cntl As Control In parent.Controls

        If Cntl.Name.ToLower = name.ToLower Then

            Return Cntl
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

    Return Nothing

End Function
```